# Set a JavaScript variable from JSP (server side) bwithout reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to set a JavaScript variable from JSP without causing the entire page to reload.  The code I have now sets the variable, but reloads the entire page as a side effect.

example.jsp:

```
    <html>
      <select name="country" id="country"onchange="getCountryI()">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="india">India</option>
        <option value="aus">Austrila</option>
        <option value="uk">U.K</option>
        <option value="eng">England</option>
        <option value="westindies">West-Indies</option>
      </select>
    </html>
    <script>
      function getCountryI() {
        alert(3);
        var id = document.getElementById("country").value;
        window.location.replace("example.jsp?name=" + id);
      }
</script>
      <%
         String value = request.getParameter("name");
         System.out.println("value is" + value);
         out.println("valuevaluevalue" + value);
       %>
```

Comment: `window.location.replace` will do that, if you don't want to reload, you'll need ajax.

Comment: its refreshing page is there any other way to get the value in jsp without calling ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've downloaded the page, the only ways to update a local (in-page) variable from the server is to

a) reload the page, or
b) use AJAX (JSON/P, preferably) to get the variable.

HTTP is sessionless, which means that the server-side has no way to provide data to the page on the end-user browser unless the browser initiates contact.  (Web/browser sockets aside, since they're HTML5-only.  Do you really want the server side keeping a list of all the browsers that have ever needed a response and writing code to age them off?  If you do, go right ahead--but it's easier to just AJAX it.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing the problem is inside <%%>.
The event onChange has been called and this code is "refreshing" the page. (actually changing location)

```
 window.location.replace("example.jsp?name=" + id);
```

Try debug.

Comment: its refreshing page is there any other way to get the value in jsp without using ajax call

Comment: @user3108190 AJAX is the thing that does what you want to do.  You could also move the server-side logic to client JavaScript.

Comment: ya but i tried other way but value is getting null. if i try like this entire page is reloading.is there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This part is invalid :

```
<script>
  function getCountryI() {
    alert(3);
    var id = document.getElementById("country").value;
    window.location.replace("example.jsp?name=" + id);
  }
  <%
     String value = request.getParameter("name");
     System.out.println("value is" + value);
     out.println("valuevaluevalue" + value);
   %>
</script>
```

The `out.println` will add invalid script content in the rendered page after refresh, also it will not be shown.

The `<% %>` part should be moved out of the script like this :

```
<script>
  function getCountryI() {
    alert(3);
    var id = document.getElementById("country").value;
    window.location.replace("example.jsp?name=" + id);
  }
</script>
  <%
     String value = request.getParameter("name");
     System.out.println("value is" + value);
     out.println("valuevaluevalue" + value);
   %>
```

Comment: ya i tried  but entire page is reloading.is there any other way to do this please help me out.

Comment: @user3108190 Then the way would be to use AJAX probably with jQuery.ajax for example.

Comment: with out ajax call is there any other solution

Comment: @user3108190 AJAX is the method, so this is the way to do it. You can use different libraries or do it by hand, but loading data without full refresh IS AJAX. What have you tried and what was so difficult about it?

Comment: if i use ajax that response will come in same JavaScript only how to get that java-script variable in jsp.

Answer (score 0):

You could use old-school Ajax:

```
<form action="..." method="..." target="foo">
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<iframe id="foo"></iframe>
```

You could attach an onload event handler to the `iframe` so you can extract any info that you want:

```
var foo = null;
var iframe = document.getElementById("foo");

iframe.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var win = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument;

    foo = win.foo
});
```

The response in the IFRAME could have a normal `<script>` tag that sets a global variable in that document, which you can access from the parent window.

EDIT: The key here is the `target` attribute on the FORM tag contains the value of the `id` on the IFRAME. That will cause the form to submit to the IFRAME, and load the response in the IFRAME.